# Mercedes ML350 M272 random misfire on cylinder 3 and 4

Tags: mercedes-benz

I have replaced spark plugs but am still getting misfire on cylinder 3 and 4. Sometimes it runs ok. and then other times theres no power.

Comment: Possibly a coil pack.  The pictures I have seen look like 1 coil pack does 2 cylinders on that engine, but it could be a different part to yours.

Comment: What @HandyHowie says is quite possible, sounds like an intermittent problem

Comment: Did you replace your spark plug wires?